# finding location of image using jScrollPane

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane

I have a list of images contained within jScrollPane and when you click on a image some fancy pants animations occur. The problem is I need to get the location of the image from the top of the screen. I can easily do this with jQuery when not using jScrollPane but when I use location doesn't change. How can I find the location of the image with respect to the movement within jScrollPane?

Here is an example of how I have my images displayed on screen. It's just not using jscrollpane
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/Djby5/1/)

I think this is how I need to solve this problem but I'm not sure. 
[Link to jScrollPane list item](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/auto_reinitialise.html)

how I'm building the images.

```
  grid = $('#grid'),
  str = '';

  grid.empty();
  $.each(main_images,function(i,v){
   str += '<li gallery="'+i+'"><div class="title">'+(content.navgrid[2][i].title )+'</div><a ng-href="#" class="zoom"><img src="'+main_images[i]+'"/><span></span></a></li>';
});
  grid.append($(str));

  grid.jScrollPane({hideFocus:true});
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Finding location with jscrollpane " ? can u be more specific

Comment: In your fiddle your Click function will also work with jScrollPane it will not have any problem with that until you have same ID/Class names that might cause weird behavior. Please provide more details in terms of actual requirement. and Updated fiddle in same context

Answer (score -1):

I guess if you want the top of the clicked element then that is possible with this.

```
 var position = $(this).offset().top;
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Djby5/3/)**

I am not sure is this what you wanted ??

Comment: That should probably be $(this).offset.top? I think offset().top would return an error.

Answer (score -1):

No idea what you want to do with your animation stuff, you'll need to explain that better or update with a JSFiddle that shows your problem.

I created a simple JSfiddle for you where you can see how to scroll inside a jpane to the position of the clicked element. You'll find what you need in the documentation here: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/scroll_to_animate.html

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Djby5/5/

```
//wrap in local scope
$(function()
{
   var pane = $('.scroll-pane');
    pane.jScrollPane(
        {
            showArrows: true,
            animateScroll: true
        }
    );
    var api = pane.data('jsp');

    $('.grid li').click(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('.grid')
        var offset = $(this).offset();

        //scroll to the position
        api.scrollToY(offset.top);
    });
});
```

I suggest you start simple like this, and then add your additional animations that you want ontop of this. Ovveride the animate() function in jpane and replace it with your advanced animation, or just use [jquery's animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and call `api.reinitialise();` if you alter or hide DOM elements in your animation and want the jpane scrollable area to be updated.

**EDIT**
Paste from the source code of jpane:

```
// This method is called when jScrollPane is trying to animate to a new position. You can override
// it if you want to provide advanced animation functionality. It is passed the following arguments:
//  * ele          - the element whose position is being animated
//  * prop         - the property that is being animated
//  * value        - the value it's being animated to
//  * stepCallback - a function that you must execute each time you update the value of the property
// You can use the default implementation (below) as a starting point for your own implementation.
animate: function(ele, prop, value, stepCallback)
{
    var params = {};
    params[prop] = value;
    ele.animate(
        params,
        {
            'duration'  : settings.animateDuration,
            'easing'    : settings.animateEase,
            'queue'     : false,
            'step'      : stepCallback
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: PS. my fiddle will just give you the idea on how to solve this, you'll need to add the actual div you'r using for your jpane and the correct CSS. I just put it on your ul.grid now as an example - and that's not working 100% because of your styling of the elements.